# error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type

Tags: typescript

## Error

I'm getting this typescript error:

> error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'environment' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'any'.

## Code

### package.json

```
...
"typescript": "^1.8.10",
...
```

### server.ts

```
var environment = require('./config/config.js')()
```

### ./config/config.ts

```
module.exports = function(): string {
  //Environment
  let env:string = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
  return env
}
```

## Question:

What do I need to do, to get the return value of the function recognized as a `string`?

## Edit

### tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

### Installation of node

I added a `typings.json` with

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

And as I remember uses `tsd install`. I have a folder called `typings`, In that folder is another folder called `node` with an `index.d.ts`. I assume this is the same as a `node.d.ts`?

## Edit 2

### gulp for frontend (angularjs) and backend (nodejs)

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
const paths = gulp.paths;
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

const tscConfig = require('../tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('scripts-frontend', function () {
  gulp.src(paths.src + '/systemjs.config.js')
   .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.out + '/'));

  return gulp.src([paths.src + '/frontend/**/*.ts', paths.typings + '/**/*', '!' + paths.src + '/**/*.spec.ts'])
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.out + '/frontend/'));
});

gulp.task('scripts-backend', function () {
  return gulp.src([paths.src + '/backend/**/*.ts', paths.typings + '/**/*', paths.src + '/server.ts', '!' + paths.src + '/**/*.spec.ts'])
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.out + '/backend/'));
});
```

Comment: Could you add your tsconfig.json as well? And how did you install `node.d.ts`?

Comment: I could not replicate this error. I installed the types with `typings` `1.0.4` and `1.3.1`. Using `typescript@1.8.10` to build I got no errors. Also no errors on VSCode 1.2.1 Windows... What is your version of `typings`? Try to update it maybe...

Comment: @AndiGiga, I guess `config.ts` file function may be a `fat arraow`. And also, `let env:any = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'`

Answer (score 51):

In my case it was `@types/node` that was triggering the error on AbortSignal type declaration.

- In some of my projects, **a fresh (re)install of `@types/node` to latest version** fixed the bug
- In some others, I have **uninstalled `@types/node`** which was probably duplicated somewhere. Doing so didn't change anything at my dev workflow (not sure why I installed it in the first place :-/)

Comment: As stated [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51567#issuecomment-1318523182), this can be fixed by installing the latest version via `npm i -D @types/node`, even if it's an indirect dependency (like my case).

Comment: A fresh install of @types/node worked for me!

Comment: A fresh install of @types/node worked for me as well!

Comment: Fresh install didn't work, but installing the latest @types/node worked a treat!

Answer (score 13):

Try adding --skipLibCheck flag to the tsc script

```
Ex: tsc --skipLibCheck
```

Comment: Added `"compilerOptions": {..., "skipLibCheck": true, .. }` in tsconfig.json and the TS error went away. Ty!

Comment: This Worked perfectly with typescript 4+ and Angular 15

Comment: That's a fantastic hack! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I see that your file extensions are `.ts` (e.g. `config.ts`). Don't use `var/require` in ts files! This is especially true for bringing in other `ts` files.

`var environment = require('./config/config.js')()` should be:

```
import config = require('./config/config.js'); 
const environment = config();
```

And `module.exports = function(): string {` should be :

```
export = function(): string {
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems to work nearly. I got two new problems, 
1) either I include `./config/config.js`, which is created through gulp after compiling, then I get a typescript error `src/server.ts(5,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module './config/config.js'.` because the file is not there during the typescript compilation or I require  `./config/config.ts` then I get an error at runtime.

Comment: 2) I need to switch to `"module":"commonjs"` in my `tsconfig` in order to avoid the error `System is not defined`. Now my setup was copied mainly from the angularjs homepage. DOes this mean I need to compile my typescript with two different `tsconfig` files?

Comment: I also had the problem with using `const` a lot, that it complained about redefining variables, even if the `const` was in another `js` file.

Comment: Regarding 2), this helps:
`gulp.task('scripts-backend', function () {
  tscConfig.compilerOptions.module = 'commonjs';...`

Comment: Regarding 2) Its better to use 2 tsconfigs. Editors usually seem to choose the closest one, when linting errors.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `@types/node` was pointing to the wrong version: (`node@17` while was still using `@node@16`). In general, I'ld not rely on commands like `--skipLibCheck` - they will just hide the underlying issue. Did it take me an unreasonable amount of time (removing all dependencies and re-adding them step by step) to find the issue? Yes! Would I do it again? Yes!

Answer (score 1):

In my case `@types/node` was not a direct dependency but a nested one mostly, reference by wildcard versions `"@types/node": "*"`.

Since I didn't want add it in my direct dependencies, I updated the pinned version in the package-lock by running `npm update @types/node`.